# Repeating alarm each 5 seconds to start Bluetooth scanning Doze mode Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm developing an Android app that scans Bluetooth beacons in the way to get the distance of users at indoor places. When the device is in Doze mode, the app doesn't scan, so beacons couldn't be detected. I am thinking to set an alarm (AlarmManager) that repeats each 5 seconds or less, in the way to restart the Bluetooth service and beacon scanner.

I am not sure about the way to set it and if AlarmManager is the best option because of these types of alarms in Doze mode can only be activated every 9 minutes for each app with setAndAllowWhileIdle() and setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() methods.

My application works well with Android Version <= 6.0.0, so I think that Doze mode is the problem.

Is AlarmManager a good option to restart Bluetooth services when my app is in Doze mode? How could I set a repeat-alarm to resolve this problem?

I have tested other options like a Runnable to call Bluetooth Scan Callback every 5 seconds, but after few minutes my app locks and Bluetooth Scan Callback doesn't return any beacon even though Runnable follows working correctly.

Comment: You can start a service and set it as foreground and then use handler to postdelay of 5 seconds to scan for beacon.